# Check whether a set of brackets consisting of parenthesis, square brackets, and Curly brackets are valid or not?

Tags: c++

I have a small problem here: Our teacher asked us to write a program that checks whether parenthesis, square brackets, and Curly brackets are valid. eg: `[[{{{(())}}}]]` is a valid usage but `()))`, `[[((]]))` (the latter are interleaved here) are invalid.

Here is my try:

```
int main(){
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a text: "
    cin >> input;

    int nSquareBracketRight = count(s.begin(), s.end(), '[');

    int nSquareBracketLeftt = count(s.begin(), s.end(), ']');

    if(nSquareBracketRight != nSquareBracketLeft)
        cout << "Invalid!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Valid Usage!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It looks ok above but if the occurrences are equal but if a "Closing" one is in the smaller index then it is considered invalid eg: `{}}{` Invalid.

Please help and thank you, guys!

Comment: `]]][[[` will count 3 and 3 an will be invalid. You need to loop char by char and count them as they come.

Comment: All your code is doing it counting the instances of `'['` and `']'`.   It doesn't take into account the fact that order matters  (e.g.   `][` is invalid and `[]` is valid by your criteria, but counting them as you are shows both as valid).

Answer (score 4):

This is the kind of situation that a **stack** is good for, such as [`std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack), eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool areBracketsValid(const string &input)
{
    stack<char> stk;

    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < input.size(); ++i)
    {
        char ch = input[i];
        switch (ch)
        {
            case '(':
            case '[':
            case '{':
            {
                stk.push(ch);
                break;
            }

            case ')':
            case ']':
            case '}':
            {
                if (stk.empty())
                    return false;
                char openingCh = (ch == ')') ? '(' : (ch == ']') ? '[' : '{';
                if (stk.top() != openingCh)
                    return false;
                stk.pop();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return stk.empty();
}

int main()
{
    string input;
    cout << "Enter a text: ";
    cin >> input;

    if (areBracketsValid(input))
        cout << "Valid Usage!" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Invalid!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/7Q6O25)

Comment: Thank you for your effort. But '({)}' is considered correct in your program which should not. In addition to main returns integer while it is void. And an invalid if curly bracket on line 33.

Comment: @Maestro from your example `[[{{{(())]}}}]` we can see that `({)}` is considered valid.

Comment: @Maestro - the adjustments to the code to achieve that are trivial.   When encountering a closing (`')'`, `']'`, etc) simply check that the top character of the stack is the opener (e.g. if `')'` is found, the top character should be `'('`)

Comment: @bolov It is considered incorrect please edit my question.

Comment: @Maestro - Remy's given you a starting point.   I've given you a pointer to how to adjust to meet your needs.    That's enough for you to work it out.   A little effort to actually solve your own problem won't hurt you.

Comment: @Maestro I didn't see that `{}` were also to be checked. I only checked for `()` and `[]`. I have fixed it. [Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/7Q6O25)

Comment: OP asks for help with homework and then criticizes some very thoughtful solutions.

Comment: @Peter also, in your example, `[[{{{(())]}}}]` is actually invalid (the first `]` is in the wrong place), it should be `[[{{{(())}}}]]` instead

Comment: @nicomp: I do appreciate you all but if criticising hurts I am deeply sorry. But that is the fact

Comment: @RemyLebeau - You misdirected your last comment to me.  I assume it was intended for the OP.

Comment: OP, being 'hurt' is not the issue. Taking what you were offered and making it work for you is the issue.

Comment: @Peter yes sorry

Comment: It is really helpful and works fine. @Remy thank you too much. You are really genius.

Answer (score 1):

- Using std::count is good but that is not what you need here in your program; You need something that is interested in the indexes moreover.

  You can declare for each type of brackets a variable that holds the number of its occurrences 
  and inside a loop increment the target variable if it matches the tested character.

  And right inside the loop after increment check whether the opening bracket number is smaller than the closing, 
  if so it is considered an invalid one eg: (()))( 
  As you can see above the number of opening and closing is OK but it is considered an invalid usage as the fact that a never a parenthesis begins with a closing one!

  So break the loop signaling the invalid usage.

  finally compare the number of opening and closing ones outside the loop, that is it because
  inside a loop we can open n parenthesis so the checking is only after the loop ends to get the number of closing ones. eg:
  (([[[{{{ cannot be checked inside the loop.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>

  int main(){

      std::string str;
      std::cin >> str;

      int nParR = 0, nParL = 0, nBrackR = 0, 
      nBrackL = 0, nCurlR = 0, nCurlL = 0;

      for(auto i(0); i != str.length(); ++i){
          switch(str[i]){
              case '(':
                  nParR++;
              break;
              case ')':
                  nParL++;
              break;
              case '[':
                  nBrackR++;
              break;
              case ']':
                  nBrackL++;
              break;
              case '{':
                  nCurlR++;
              break;
              case '}':
                  nCurlL++;
              break;
          }

          if(nParR < nParL || nBrackR < nBrackL || 
          nCurlR < nCurlL){
              std::cout << "Invalid usage!" << std::endl;
              break;
          }
      }

      if(nParR == nParL && nBrackR == nBrackL && nCurlR == nCurlL)
          std::cout << "Valid usage!" << std::endl;
      else
          std::cout << "Invalid Usage!";



      std::cout << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: @BenVoigt • that's a valid pattern.  They have to be balanced, but they can be interleaved.

Comment: @Eljay you are assuming they are allowed to be interleaved. It depends on the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: The question does give an example of interleaving, so Eljay may be correct.

Comment: This is tricky: Every developer with experience would expect that parentheses have to be balanced and pair-wise nested. This is how it usually works. I've read the question twice - no hint that it's required in OP's case. His attempt doesn't show any effort into this direction. For me, this answer is appropriate as the one of Remy which assumed that the OP just didn't understand the assignment correctly. ;-)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I solved it my own way. I'd like you to realize it using "stack"  because using a stack here may add some charm.

Comment: @Raindrop7 I already solved it using a stack my way. I'm not going to rewrite your way to use a stack, too

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Yes. I took a look at yours. It is really better than mine. What drawbacks of mine? if you could take a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is really easy to achieve: Let's say you have an input like this: `([{}])` it is considered correct isn't it? but `([)]` is invalid.

In the correct one you can see in some point that `element i` is an opening bracket and `element i + 1` is a closing bracket of the same family of brackets. Which is considered valid So the trick is to remove this subset brackets until the stack/vector is empty. If so then the whole input is correct otherwise is invalid.

- Tip: inside a loop erase `element i` and `element i + 1` if only and if element i is opening and element i + 1 is closing and `element i` and `element i + 1` are of the same family eg: `{}, [], ()`.

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  #include <vector>


  int main(){

      std::string str = "[({}{})]"; // valid
  //  std::string str = "["; // invalid
  //  std::string str = "[(])"; // invalid
  //  std::string str = "[({}{})]]"; // invalid
  //  std::string str = "[({}{}])"; // invalid
  //  std::string str = "{{}[{}]{(())}}"; // valid
  //  std::string str = "][(){}"; // invalid
      std::vector<char> vecStr;
      bool isDone = false;


      for(auto i(0); i != str.length(); ++i)
          vecStr.push_back(str[i]);

      for(auto i(0); i != vecStr.size(); ++i)
          std::cout << vecStr[i];
      std::cout << std::endl;

      for(auto i(0); i < str.length() / 2 && !isDone; ++i){
          for(auto j(0) ; j < vecStr.size() - 1; ++j){
              if(!vecStr.size()){
                  isDone = true;
                  break;
              }
              switch(vecStr[j]){
                  case '{':
                      if(vecStr[j + 1] == '}'){
                          vecStr.erase(&vecStr[j]);
                          vecStr.erase(&vecStr[j]);
                      }
                  break;
                  case '(':
                      if(vecStr[j + 1] == ')'){
                          vecStr.erase(&vecStr[j]);
                          vecStr.erase(&vecStr[j]);
                      }
                  break;
                  case '[':
                      if(vecStr[j + 1] == ']'){
                          vecStr.erase(&vecStr[j]);
                          vecStr.erase(&vecStr[j]);
                      }
                  break;
              }
          }
      }

      std::cout << "size: " << vecStr.size() << std::endl;

      if(vecStr.size())
          std::cout << "Invalid Input!" << std::endl;
      else
          std::cout << "valid Input!" << std::endl;

      std::cout << std::endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```
- just switch uncommenting the input lines above and see the result. Or input it using `std::cin`.

Comment: @Maestro: Please edit the question. So that interleaved brackets are invalid. eg: `[(])` is invalid.